# Remove extra space before first letter of text so it can be properly aligned to the left

Tags: android, text, vertical-alignment

I have several exact same `TextView`s aligned vertically (same margin left, same padding left, same position left). They could have different text size, as well as the text could start with a different letter. The problem is that, although the `TextView`s are aligned to the left, the text in them is not. Is it possible to achieve this? To remove/factor the extra space before each first letter? Or should I be looking for some specific font?

The pictures below show the situation. There are three `TextView`s aligned to the left, but each letter starts at a different point. *s* and *m* have the same size, but are not aligned. *i* is quite smaller and the gap is much bigger.

What I am seeing:
[image: Actual]

What I want:
[image: Expected result (manually aligned)]

Code of the example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="m"
        android:textColor="#88FF0000"
        android:textSize="250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="s"
        android:textColor="#8800FF00"
        android:textSize="250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:text="i"
        android:textColor="#880000FF"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with a TextView. You *might* be able to use a canvas and draw the text yourself, using information from `Paint.getTextWidths()`, though I have no idea if the widths returned from that includes the surrounding whitespace (my guess is that it won't help).

Comment: I do believe it's possible with the TextView, it just needs a MonoSpaced font.

Comment: I've tried `android:typeface="monospace"` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, I just came across the same issue and found a solution as follows, maybe it can help someone else:

Create a TextView subclass and override it's `onDraw()` method as follows:

```
// bounds field to avoid allocations in onDraw()
Rect bounds = new Rect();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    getPaint().getTextBounds(getText().toString(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
    canvas.translate(-bounds.left, 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

**Caveat**: Although I have observed the text bounds to have a left value that corresponds to the amount of empty pixels before the first letter, and is in line with the documentation of `Paint#getTextBounds()` which states that it returns

> the smallest rectangle that encloses all of the characters, with an implied origin at (0,0),

thus the left value is where the actual text starts, this fix may not work for all typefaces or configurations.

It should also be noted that this is a simple solution for left-aligned single line text; multiline or scrolled text will need further adjustments or may not work with this at all.

Comment: Thanks for the submission. Will check your solution at first convenience and update the answer's status.